# Cannot read Tamil characters (கோயம்புத்தூர்) in C# from xml Response

Tags: c#, xml, http

I am using C# windows app to get the response from tally in XML format. I can get details while the data are like symbol and special characters. But I could not get any other languages data like Tamil, Hindi etc. So how do I get it!?

Expected O/P: பாண்டியன் 450, கோயம்புத்தூர்

Received O/P: ????????? 450, ??????????????

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://localhost:{0}", "9000"));
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());

streamWriter.Write(xml);
streamWriter.Close();

HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.Default, true))
{
    responsefromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Try `Encoding.UTF8` for the StreamReader argument

Comment: I tried. But the result is the same.

Comment: It could be that the server doesn't handle Unicode. Could you please show the bytes which the server responds with? You can get the bytes from the `dataStream` by creating a `MemoryStream` and using `CopyTo` to copy the data there, then using `ToArray` to get out a byte array.

Comment: And I'm just guessing here but could it be that your `xml` has already broken the letters? Are you reading the xml somewhere with `Encoding.Default`?

Comment: I am too getting same error, please share fix if found